# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'data') is this due to the type I've given my useState?

Tags: typescript, typeerror, react-tsx

I'm receiving this error in my terminal although my code and tests are running fine:

```
src/components/Weather.tsx:31
    setWeather(response.data.result.weather);
                        ^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'data')
    at fetchWeatherData
```

I've looked for some answers online and it is quite broad most seem to be typos but I don't think that's the case here.

This is my component:

```
import axios from 'axios';
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { IWeather } from '../interfaces/IWeather';
import { MdWbSunny } from 'react-icons/md';
import { IoIosPartlySunny } from 'react-icons/io';
import { BsFillCloudSnowFill } from 'react-icons/bs';
import { Title, Text } from '@mantine/core';

const Weather = () => {
  const [weather, setWeather] = useState<IWeather | null>();

  const fetchWeatherData = async () => {
    const response = await axios.get('http://mock-api-call/weather/get-weather');
    setWeather(response.data.result.weather);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchWeatherData();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <>
        <Title order={2}>
          {weather?.forcast === 'Sunny' ? (
            <MdWbSunny />
          ) : weather?.forcast === 'Snowing' ? (
            <BsFillCloudSnowFill />
          ) : (
            <IoIosPartlySunny />
          )}
        </Title>
      </>
      <Text size="xl">{weather?.forcast}</Text>
      <Text size="lg">Temp: {`${weather?.min} to ${weather?.max}`}</Text>
      <Text size="md">{weather?.description}</Text>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Weather;
```

the error is mentioning line 31. Which is this block in the Weather component:

```
 <Title order={2}>
          {weather?.forcast === 'Sunny' ? (
            <MdWbSunny />
          ) : weather?.forcast === 'Snowing' ? (
            <BsFillCloudSnowFill />
          ) : (
            <IoIosPartlySunny />
          )}
        </Title>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to debug like so :

```
  const fetchWeatherData = async () => {
    const response = await axios.get('http://mock-api-call/weather/get-weather', (request, response) => {
        console.log('request', request);
        console.log('response', response);
        setWeather(response.data.result.weather);
    });
    
  };
```

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

It seems like it's not a valid api url, in order to detect what the issue is , i would like to add try/catch block to the fetch function :

```
const fetchWeatherData = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await axios.get('http://mock-api-call/weather/get-weather');
     // Just put some log to ensure you have the response.
     const {data} = response;
     if (data?.result?.weather) {
        setWeather(data?.result?.weather);
      }
    } catch(error) {
      console.log("An Error is occured : ", error);
    }
  };
```